# Java - Load PHP Webpage (Just LOAD)

Tags: java, load, html

All I need is a simple way to load a webpage. I have a PHP script setup, that I just need Java to load.

I've tried HttpURLConnection, but that doesn't seem to work :/ Here's the code I tried:

```
HttpURLConnection webpage = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
webpage.setRequestMethod("GET");
webpage.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
webpage.connect();
```

No error, just the page doesn't load. If I load the page in the browser it works fine.

I don't need it to read the page or anything, just load it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you put the code for the initialization of the variable "url" ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "load"?  Do you just want to hit the URL on the server, without paying attention to any of the data that comes back?  Because that should be what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to call `getContent()` in order for the page to actually be loaded (or `getInputStream()`, or some other equivalent)

I don't have the source for sun's internal `HttpURLConnection` implementation, but as best I can tell from reading the bytecode, `connect()` opens an `OutputStream` to the server but doesn't actually write anything to it.